# Mysql Stored Procedure - No rows fetched

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm new to Mysql Stored Procedures.
Tring to return rows in a stored procedure after a LOOP.
Here's my code

```
BEGIN
    
    DECLARE date_SD date;
    DECLARE c_stack CURSOR FOR
      select SD from t4 where date(SD) >= "2022-05-01" and date(SD)<= "2022-05-30" group by SD;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS final_result;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE final_result LIKE templaedb.temp_table;
    
    OPEN c_stack;
    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH c_stack INTO date_SD;
        INSERT INTO final_result VALUES ('first','140','2022-05-06','','1','2','3','4','5');
        INSERT INTO final_result VALUES ('last','500','2022-05-06','','11','12','13','14','15');
    END LOOP read_loop;
    CLOSE c_stack;
    select 'Print Test';
    select * from final_result;
END
```

Select statement at last of the Stored Procedure is not working.

Comment: Why aren't you using the `date_SD` variable?

Comment: The only reason I can think is that the `SELECT` query is not returning anything.

Comment: @Barmar I'm using date_SD variable in my full stored procedure. I have removed those lines for stackoverflow

Comment: Do you see anything in the temporary table if you check it after calling the SP?

Comment: You have an infinite loop

Comment: @Barmar I also wonder why `SELECT` is not returning any result

Comment: How are you fetching the results? Since you have two `SELECT` statements in the SP, it returns two result sets.

Comment: @P.Salmon the loops completed in 0.0013 seconds. The loop is working fine. FYI `SELECT` is working inside the loop.

Comment: Try getting rid of `select 'Print Test'` so you only returns one result set.

Comment: @Barmar Added `Select 'Print Test'` for debugging purpose. To check basic SELECT  is working or not. I have tried of removing it also.

Comment: Asking again: What do you see if you do `select * from final_result` after the procedure returns?

Comment: @Barmar Error Code: 1329. No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed

Comment: Need to add `DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND` and change the looping

Comment: See https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/525969/1329plusNoplusdataplus-pluszeroplusrowsplusfetched#:~:text=1329%20No%20data%20%2D%20zero%20rows%20fetched%2C%20selected%2C%20or%20processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    DECLARE date_SD date;
            DECLARE c_stack CURSOR FOR
              select SD from t4 where date(SD) >= "2022-05-01" and date(SD)<= "2022-05-30" group by SD;
         
         /* add this*/ DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;
            DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS final_result;
            CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE final_result LIKE templaedb.temp_table;
            OPEN c_stack;
            read_loop: LOOP
            FETCH c_stack INTO date_SD;
/* must include*/
            IF done = 1 THEN
             LEAVE read_loop;
            END IF;
/* must include*/
                INSERT INTO final_result VALUES ('first','140','2022-05-06','','1','2','3','4','5');
                INSERT INTO final_result VALUES ('last','500','2022-05-06','','11','12','13','14','15');
            END LOOP read_loop;
            CLOSE c_stack;
            select * from final_result;
```